# How to get href in HTML Agility Pack?

Tags: c#

i want to get "href" link in this html node.
I already trying, but the result still not work.

This is the code:

```
<a title="ASUS ROG" class="product-media__link js-tracker-product-link" href="https://www.bukalapak.com/p/komputer/laptop/8vl4vm-jual-asus-rog?search%5Bkeywords%5D=asus%20rog&amp;from=omnisearch">
```

Comment: When you were "trying", but it "still not work", please add the code you were trying (not just the HTML) and add details about *what* didn't work (any compile-time or runtime errors, wrong result).

Answer (score 2):

Here are some sample code to extract the href url on the page:

```
HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.Load("yourpage.html");
var link = htmlDoc.DocumentNode
                  .Descendants("a")
                  .First(x => x.Attributes["title"] != null 
                           && x.Attributes["title"].Value == "ASUS ROG");

string hrefValue = link.Attributes["href"].Value;
```